# Is there any ordered Map in gnu trove library?

Tags: java, trove4j

I am using a `LinkedHashMap<Double, String>` in my program. But I need one with primitive data types. In trove we have map but it is not ordered? Any idea about ordered one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not currently a LinkedHashMap-analogous implementation in Trove. A feature request exists [here](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/issue/12/linkedhashmap). Voting there would be useful if it's a feature you're still interested in.

Answer (score -3):

It is not a problem at all
Use this:

```
    private TDoubleObjectMap<String> obj = new TDoubleObjectHashMap<String>();
```

where TDoubleObjectMap comes from gnu.trove.map and HashMap comes from gnu.trove.map.hash;
P.S. It looks like there isn't linked map classes.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question

Comment: How can TDoubleObjectHashMap be used as an Ordered map?